# VueJs Laravel 7 - Better Way Structure Projects

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i 'm using VueJs on my Laravel project , my project has this structure .

i have a blade file called "app.blade.php" where inside this blade i put my .css files and my script files that i wanna user , include "app.js" .

after this i have some others pages , like for example , a.blade.php , b.blade.php , because theses pages i'll extends layout from app.blade.php .

but imagine that on page a.blade.php i wanna use a component vue called CarComponent .

so in a.blade.php i create a div like this

```
<div id="app>
<CarComponent></CarComponent>
</div>
```

and imagine that in my b.blade i wanna use a component called "StoreComponent"

```
<div id="app">
<StoreComponent></StoreComponent>
</div>
```

in my file resources/js/app.js , i have for examples this structure :

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('CarComponent',require('./components/CarComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('StoreComponent',require('./components/StoreComponent.vue').default);

const app= new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

but sometimes , i dont wanna use vuejs on some pages , so warn that cannot find element "#app" . have a way to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following structure and it works very well:

on the app.blade.php, I have a main div like this:

```
<div class="container" id="app">
   @yield('content')
</div>
```

so, basically, the div with id="app" exists in all views, no matter if it is Vue or not.

Then, I have another blade component (component.blade.php) that is just this:

```
@extends('layouts/app')
@section('content')
<{{ $component }}
    @if(isset($params))
        @foreach($params as $param => $val)
            @if(is_object($val) || is_array($val))
                :{{$param}} = "{{ json_encode($val) }}"
            @else
                {{$param}} = "{{$val}}"
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif
/>
@stop
```

and then on my controllers, I do the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class CarController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $params = [
            'foo' => 'bar',
       ];

        return view('component')
            ->with('params', $params)
            ->with('component', 'CarComponent');
    }
}
```

and finally, on my CarComponent.vue, I can get those params like this:

```
export default {
    props: [
        'foo'
    ],
}
```

You also keep your blade files to a minimum and re-use a lot of code.